# Express app.get array

Tags: node.js, express, http-get

At the moment, I'm using a variable called 'config.prefix' in my app.get:

```
app.get(config.prefix + "/stats", function(req, res) {}
```

I would like to be able to set config.prefix to an array (or do it a totally different way) that I can add multiple prefixes too. Is this possible? Or would I have to hard code every app.get call for every prefix I want?

Thanks, Nevexo.

Comment: You could wrap your get declarations in a for loop and iterate over the prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to code each route. Or you could just use a loop. e.g.

```
for (var i = 0; i < config.prefix.length; i++) {
  app.get(config.prefix[i] + "/stats", config.prefix.handler)
}
```

Assuming `config.prefix` is an array and you have the handler function somewhere you can use without hard coding.

This might be something to create a middleware function for.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I'll try that. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad that helped! If it answered your question, please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark next to it 

Comment: Hey, sorry to re-open this, but I've been working on this project again recently, I have the endpoints being created based off the code you sent above, and I can see the endpoints when I request app._router.stack, but when I get request one of the endpoints, it shows the data that the final thing to load would have in it. Hope that makes sense.